# Type override in generic protocol giving "explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue" error

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4

I am trying to change the default associated type to String. but getting this error

> explicitly specify the generic arguments to fix this issue.

Below code works fine for type **Int** but not for **String**. Am i missing something?

```
//override/Change the associated Type of Protocol

protocol Familiable{
    associatedtype FamilyType = Int
    func getName()->[FamilyType]
}

class NumberFamily:Familiable{

    func getName() -> [Int] {
        return [1,2,3,4,5]
    }
}

let numRef = NumberFamily()
print(numRef.getName())
type(of: numRef)

struct NormalFamily<T:ExpressibleByStringLiteral>: Familiable{

    func getName() -> [T] {
        return ["name1","name2"]
    }

}

let normalRef = NormalFamily()
normalRef.getName()
```

Comment: You say _Below code works fine for type **Int**_, but your `NormalFamily<T:ExpressibleByStringLiteral>` never works for `Int` (`NormalFamily<Int>` always causes compile-time error). What do you mean?

Comment: Yes you're rite.i mean it works fine only for the class NumberFamily which adopts Familiable protocol. but its not working for same protocol adopted by  struct NormalFamily.i just want to make protocol generic for both the types.